# Breakout indicator Alert: Bollinger Band breaking out from inside a Donchian Channel

Tags: metatrader4, mt4

I am totally new to coding in Metatrader 4.

I need help or an example of coding a
Breakout indicator Alert:
Bollinger Band breaking out from inside a Donchian Channel.

Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 1):

Whit 0 of programing skill, will be difficult but ,
try on forex factory this thread:"I will code your expert/indicator for no charge"